# Trying to get website API Content in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello StackOverflow community, I have got into a issue where I am trying to get content off of a website's api, this is what the source says: {"url":"blablabla"}, this is what I'm trying to get: blablabla, This is my code for now:

```
        function stripHtml(html){
            var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");
            temporalDivElement.innerHTML = html;
            return temporalDivElement.textContent || temporalDivElement.innerText || "";
        }
            var htmlString = `{"url":"blablabla"}`
            htmlString.replace(`{"url":"}`, '');
```

Comment: I do not get what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to split a url in the content of the website

Comment: I still do not get it. Do you just want to parse the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch"); // Use npm i node-fetch if you don't have it already.

fetch("API URL").then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
    // Let's imagine that the data is: {"url": "blablabla"}
    console.log(data.url);
    // --> blablabla
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me use the api and understand a little more about nodejs. If you have discord yourself please add me: varrious#6973

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, the solution is:

```
var data = `{"url": "blablabla"}`
var result = JSON.parse(data).url
```

Comment: instead of the [var data = `{"url": "blablabla"}`] how can I make it be the actual source instead of the blablabla

Comment: I also get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)